# Casting bit data To and From float

Tags: c#, c++, encoding, floating-point, glsl

I have a problem that I want to pack very specific data into specific bits and store them in a float. I already investigated ways of simply packing numbers into floats, but using simple math won't work for what I want because I need to use the full 32 bits to store very specific values.  If it was a 32 bit integer, this would be very easy.

So what I want to do is encode the data as a 32 bit integer and then turn this bit data directly into a float with all the bits remaining the same (unless someone has a better suggestion on how to do it). What languages will allow me to do a conversion like this?  Obviously, not javascript and python because they don't support 32 bit floats. Will C# or C++ do it?

I need to decode the data in a GLSL or HLSL vertex shader.   The shader would, of course, receive the 32 bit float.  Is there an operator that will allow me to turn the float directly to integer with all the same bits instead of an ordinary cast?  Or perhaps some other way to read the bits directly?

---

UPDATE:  Eric Postpischil showed how to easily do the direct conversion in C in an answer below.  Now I just need to know if there's a way to do a direct conversion from float to int or bit data in a vertex shader.  Can anyone help on that part?

Comment: NaN's are irrelevant.  The data isn't meant to be interpreted as a float.  It's merely stored in a float, for performance and mesh restriction reasons.  Furthermore, storing data in a texture has nowhere NEAR the performance of passing data per vertex down the pipe.  Texture lookups are extremely costly.  It also adds complexity to keep a huge LUT texture array for a giant mesh.

Comment: I wasn't referring to NaN's, but rather genuinely illegal bit patterns. Whether or not those figures are interpreted as floating point values is outside your control.

Comment: @IInspectable: In IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point, all bit patterns are defined. Each pattern is either +0, -0, a specific unique non-zero finite number, +infinity, -infinity, or a quiet or signaling NaN. If you do not count NaNs, there are no illegal bit patterns.

Comment: Do you really need all 32 bits? A `float` can hold 24 bit integers plus an extra sign bit.

Comment: This is all irrelevant as the OpenGL Shading Language has no support for reinterpreting a value as a different type. There are no pointers, no type unions, no implicit type changes and no reinterpret casts. If you pass a float, it simply is a float. Forever. @Eric That's true, thanks for pointing that out. Still, denormals will likely be flushed to zero, for performance reasons.

Comment: For HLSL Shader Model 4 and above the [`asuint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509573.aspx) intrinsic is available. For Shader Model 5 and above, the [`asuint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471354.aspx) function is available.

Comment: What is your target hardware? Modern GPUs support everything necessary to skip packing these things into floating-point and simply use integers throughout the entire pipeline.

Comment: @IInspectable, after following your link to the asuint description, I saw a similar function called "asint" that says it interprets any bit pattern as an integer.  It doesn't give any specifics about input restrictions, so I'm assuming if I give it a 32 bit float, I'll get a 32 bit Int.  That would do precisely what I need.  Also, You seem to be making a lot of conflicting statements.  First you talk as if it's impossible nonsense, then you link to the asuint function which helps solve the problem.  Are you thinking before you say stuff?

Comment: @Andon Coleman: Target hardware is ultra modern.  The issue pertains more to using existing 3d engine that has standard floating point UVs stored in mesh vertices.  I have to work with what the engine wants.  I'm packing data in the mesh vertex UVs.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: yes I want to use all 32 bits.  I didn't have any problem packing 3 small integers into the mantissa.  It's working well. But I wanted to pack a 4th number as an 8 bit integer into the exponent.  Unfortunately, I'm running into a wall with the range restriction of 10^38.  I might end up doing the IntegerToFloat trick you suggested with C.  Right now I'm using an application-specific script and so I have to treat a float as a float during the packing process.  I anticipated this problem and that's the whole reason I started this thread.  I just want to pack the float with 32 bits.

Comment: @Jim the answer I gave in your other question is how you get to 24 bits. Beyond that it won't work, sorry.

Comment: @Jim Your question is tagged [glsl] and you explicitly called for a GLSL shader in a comment to another answer so I assumed you were looking for an OpenGL solution. Rereading the question I also spotted the HLSL and provided the links to the DirectX documentation. It's rare that people ask for a solution that works either with DirectX or OpenGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in C with:

```
#include <stdint.h>

float IntegerToFloat(uint32_t u)
{
    return (union { uint32_t u; float f; }) {u} .f;
}

uint32_t FloatToInteger(float f)
{
    return (union { float f; uint32_t u; }) {f} .u;
}
```

Naturally, this requires that `float` be 32 bits in the C implementation, and that `uint32_t` be a supported type (but you can use another 32-bit integer type if it is not, likely `unsigned int`). Some of the resulting `float` values may be NaNs, which might not remain unchanged in certain operations, such as conversion for printing or display and conversion back. Even normal `float` values will not generally remain unchanged unless they are displayed with sufficient precision and the C implementation uses correct rounding for decimal-to-binary and binary-to-decimal conversions.

So abusing the bits like this is a bad idea unless it is compelled with no alternative.

Comment: I figured C could probably do it.  I knew it was going to give wacky NaN values, and I appreciate you pointing out that it require extra care to make sure the bits don't get changed unexpectedly.  This is what I have to do to accomplish the result, though.  It's going to have a huge positive performance impact.  Now I hope someone will just give me some GLSL shader insight on whether or not I can unpack the bits from a float that might be NaN.